# How to make Menu Company Profile Website in google search ? how to edit sitemap.xml to setting it?

Tags: javascript, php, search, seo

How to make Menu Company Profile Website in google search like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUDd5.png)

Answer (score -1):

Google only show Sitelinks for results when Google think they’ll be useful to the user. If the structure of your site doesn’t allow Google algorithms to find good Sitelinks, or Google don’t think that the Sitelinks for your site are relevant for the user’s query, Google won’t show them.